# How can I improve efficiency of this macro?

Tags: macros

I run Vim with pdftex through latexmk, which I only use at runtime, and native Vim highlighting for LaTeX. I have following two macros in my preamble to help me organize my thoughts during a lecture:

```
\newcommand{\Def}[2]%
{%
    {\footnotesize%
        {\noindent\textbf{#1}%
        { \setlength{\parskip}{0pt} #2}}%
    \par}%
}

%makro do akapitow
\newcommand{\Par}[2]%
{%
    {\footnotesize%
    {\color[rgb]{0.301, 0.364, 0.325}  %
        { \noindent\textit{#1}}%
        { \setlength{\parskip}{0pt} #2}%
    }%
    \par}%
}%
```

The problem is, when writing a very long proof using Par, Vim starts being uneasingly slow, ie it takes noticeable time from me pushing a button to a glyph appearing on the screen. This ends instantly after closing the bracket `}`. This disrupts the flow of longer arguments. The problem seems to be mostly with Par macro, although with Def macro it's noticeable as well. Is this something intrinsic to LaTeX, and if so, what can I do to improve the efficiency of this code?

Comment: Vim is an editor, unrelated to LaTeX. Your code is fine but LaTeX is only acting on it when actually compiling. Probably you should file a bug for the syntax highlighter you are using. Another question: How about closing the brace when opening it and writing everything in between; does that also exhibit a slowdown?

Comment: Yes, that does it as well.

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/231952

Comment: That's an editor issue; on the other hand, feeding a long proof as a single argument is not really the best way to go. Why not using an environment?